# Getting rid of confusion regarding NoSQL databases

Tags: cassandra, database, nosql

This question is about NoSQL (for instance take cassandra).

- Is it true that when you use a NoSQL database without data replication that you have no consistency concerns? Also not in the case of access concurrency?
- What happens in case of a partition where the same row has been written in both partitions, possible multiple times? When the partition is gone, which written value is used?
- Let's say you use N=5 W=3 R=3. This means you have guaranteed consistency right? How good is it to use this quorum? Having 3 nodes returning the data isn't that a big overhead?
- Can you specify on a per query basis in cassandra whether you want the query to have guaranteed consistency? For instance you do an insert query and you want to enforce that all replica's complete the insert before the value is returned by a read operation?
- If you have: employees{PK:employeeID, departmentId, employeeName, birthday} and department{PK:departmentID, departmentName} and you want to get the birthday of all employees with a specific department name. Two problems:

  1. you can't ask for all the employees with a given birthday (because you can only query on the primary key)
  2. You can't join the employee and the department column families because joins are impossible.

So what you can do is create a column family:

**departmentBirthdays{PK:(departmentName, birthday), [employees-whos-birthday-it-is]}**

In that case whenever an employee is fired/hired it has to be removed/added in the departmentBirthdays column family. Is this process something you have to do manually? So you have to manually create queries to update all redundant/denormalized data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer this from the perspective of cassandra, coz that's what you seem to be looking at (hardly any two nosql stores are the same!).

1. For a single node, all operations are in sequence. Concurrency issues can be orthogonal though...your web client may have made a request, and then another, but due to network load, cassandra got the second one first. That may or may not be an issue. There are approaches around such problems, like immutable data. You can also leverage "lightweight transactions".
2. Cassandra uses last write wins to resolve conflicts. Based on you replication factor and consistency level for your query, this can work well.
3. Quurom for reads AND writes will give you consistency. There is an edge case..if the coordinator doesn't know a quorum node is down, it sends the write requests, then the write would complete when quorum is re-established. The client in this case would get a timeout and not a failure. The subsequent query may get the stale data, but any query after that will get latest data. This is an extreme edge case, and typically N=5, R=3, W3= will give you full consistency. Reading from three nodes isn't actually that much of an overhead. For a query with R=3, the client would make that request to the node it's connected to (the coordinator). The coordinator will query replicas in parallel (not sequenctially). It willmerge up the results with LWW to get the result (and issue read repairs etc. if needed). As the queries happen in parallel, the overhead is greatly reduced.
4. Yes.
5. This is a matter of data modelling. You describe one approach (though partitioning on birthday rather than dept might be better and result in more even distribution of partitions). Do you need the employee and department tables...are they needed for other queries? If not, maybe you just need one. If you denormalize, you'll need to maintain the data manually. In Cassandra 3.0, global indexes will allow you to query on an index without being inefficient (which is the case when using a secondary index without specifying the partition key today). Yes another option is to partition employeed by birthday and do two queries, and do the join in memory in the client. Cassandra queries hitting a partition are very fast, so doing two won't really be that expensive.